# Percentage parts adjustment

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $3$ variable components that are percentages and $X+Y+Z$ always equals $100$. I cannot seem to find the proper way to calculate $Y$ and $Z$ if I increase $X$ by $25$ for example. I know it is a very stupid question but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem well, you want to find $Y'$ and $Z'$ so that:

- $X'+Y'+Z'=100$
- $\frac{Y}{Z}=\frac{Y'}{Z'}$

assuming $Z\neq 0$ and $X'$ is the new, fixed value of $X$.

Solving this system yields:

$Z' = \frac{100-X'}{\frac{Y}{Z}+1}$ and $Y' = \frac{Y}{Z}Z'$

Comment: Yes! Thank you - if my old math teachers saw me now.... Anyway that was fast :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: Of course i forgot - what about 4 components, ill to apply it myself but it would be good to hear from you, also im not confident ill succeed at all. Should i make another question if i cant do it?

Comment: Generalization is quite straightforward: Say you have $k$ variables $X_1,\dots ,X_k$. If you want to assign a new value $X_1'$ to $X_1$ then the system you have to solve is: $$ \sum_{i=1}^k X_k' = 100$$ and for $1< i \leqslant k$, $$ \frac{X_i}{X_{i+1}} = \frac{X_i'}{X_{i+1}'}$$